# object arrays are not currently supported

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. (I'm using python 3 on canopy)
Here is a sample of my code:

```
dat =pd.read_csv('myfile',sep=',')
dat=dat.values
P=np.ones((240,1))
Y=dat[:,15] 

for i in range (2,15):
    X= np.column_stack((P,(dat[:,i])))
    Xt = np.transpose(X)
    p=np.matmul(Xt,X)
```

I originally input my data as a dataframe but changed it to an np array, and when I check all the data types in X they are floats, and X is created okay, however, when I try to use matmul on it returns the error

```
TypeError: object arrays are not currently supported
```

I'm confused as all the elements seem to be floats but it won't multiply. 
Thanks

Comment: `matmul` calculates the matrix product of two arrays. Your arrays should be matrix shaped arrays not object arrays.

Comment: @Kasramvd yes- my problem is why is it an object array, and how do I make it a matrix shaped array? It looks like a normal array when I print it.

Comment: Pandas often creates object dtype arrays.  What's `dat.dtype`?

Comment: @hpaulj it gives "dtype('O')"

Comment: Do you know about the `astype` method?

Comment: @ hpaulj yes - I just found this now- thanks!